# What movie or TV show is this shuttle-craft prop from?

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction, props

I'm trying to find out what movie or TV show this sci fi-looking prop is from. I saw the prop, appearing to be some kind of shuttle-craft, recently at the Aviation Warehouse in El Mirage and I suspect it's from a relatively new production.

[image: Black shuttle]

[image: Interior][image: Front]

Comment: Do you have any additional shots, especially of the interior?

Comment: I thought it might have been the cab section of Serenity, but I don't believe so after looking at some images from Google.

Comment: I've added a couple of more images.

Comment: Looks almost F-117ish. The cockpit area seems too spacey though, so perhaps a B2? I thought it was Stealth, but looking at some movie stills ruled that out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I didn't watch the movie, but some Googling has revealed that this is a helicopter from the [Zero Dark Thirty (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1790885/combined) movie.

You can watch a [YouTube clip where it can be seen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-OE7QC4gC0), and here three stories that confirm/explain it: [one](http://www.wired.com/dangerroom/2012/08/movie-prop-or-stealth/), [two](http://deepbluehorizon.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/real-stealth-helicopter-or-movie-prop.html), [three](http://filmmakeriq.com/2012/12/building-osama-bin-ladens-compound-for-zero-dark-thirty/).

This is from the last link:
[image: Zero Dark Thirty helicopter]

Comment: Well done - I was image searching this one for ages ;)